# Circuit for slow windturbine 3-Phase

Tags: batteries, capacitor, circuit-design, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

I have a little problem over here. Me and my friend wanted to make a low cost windturbine from scratch for our last school project, we have 24 magnets(size 40x10x4 mm) and 9 coils(1.4mm copperwire and ±56turns).The 9 coils will be in this formation[image: Coil setup]
So we will get 3phase. We asked a friend of he could make the circuit for us, because we do not have the knowledge for it.

I did some research and now I know that we need from the 3-phase generator a Bridge Rectifier to a Capacitor to a "loadingcircuit" to a 12v car battery (or any accu) then back to AC if we get enough power for a electrical outlet or a usb 5V port, something like that. But i don't now what kind of Bridge Rectifier i need and Capacitor etc. The question is what do i need for a circuit that can go from a slow windturbine 3-phase to a 5V usb Output or 12V or the AC 230V eletrical outlet

I don't know if I'm in the right place for this question, but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can easily find a 3 phase diode bridge but V (with no load) is proportional to RPM and Current is proportional to torque available and magnetic flux strength and electrically measured by resistance between output and load cap and often regulated by a pulsed inductor with PWM. This is not a trivial task to optimize even for 5V or 12V DC. Your coils may be series or parallel wound. Not possible for  230Vac with such low power. When the load R is too much (low R) the voltage will drop due to load/(load+source impedance) ratio.

Comment: I started editing your question to clean up some of the mess, but too much was required.  For example, the whole first sentence is completely fluff that disrespects everyone's time.  Then "Me and my friend"!?  This isn't 5th grade anymore where bad English might be excused.  There are several sentences with no space after them.  The last sentence is also purely disrespecting fluff.  -1 for dumping slop on us.  Ping me after fixing, and I'll undo it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bridge
As for the voltage it depends on the number of the turns and RPMs[image]

Comment: That is only the bridge and this is a a 6-phase bridge and I only need a 3 phase bridge, how do I know what kind of capicator i need with the bridge etc.

Comment: It's really hard to say, which cap might be suitable, because self made projects don't provide a datasheet. Perhaps try 100 to 470uF electrolytic capacitor and choose the correct electric strength! However this depends on the coils, the speed, the magnet,... everything